# Clion+MinGW+SDL2+CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion, sdl2

Пожалуйста помогите исправить ошибку.

файлы из папки SDL закинул в папку с MinGW

**main.cpp**

```
'#include <iostream>
 #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

  //Screen dimension constants
  const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
  const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
  int main( int argc, char* args[] )
  {
//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* window = NULL;

//The surface contained by the window
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
}
else
{
    //Create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Get window surface
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

        //Fill the surface white
        SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

        //Wait two seconds
        SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    }
}
//Destroy window
SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

//Quit SDL subsystems
SDL_Quit();

return 0; }'
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

> ```
>   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
>   project(Pong)
>
>   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
>
>
>
>   find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
>
>   include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
>
>   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
>
>   add_executable(Pong main.cpp)
>
>   target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARY} -lmingw32  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows)'
> ```

**Ошибка**

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Pong.exe
CMakeFiles\Pong.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:/Users/Ilya/CLionProjects/Pong/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\Pong.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'Pong.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Pong.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Pong.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Pong.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Pong.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Pong.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Pong] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Pong' failed
```

---

Вопрос решён! Сайт полное ... Всем кто помог большое спасибо!

Comment: Да, файл есть . FindSDL2.cmake

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857351/linking-sdl2-and-clion), может поможет

Comment: *"файлы из папки SDL закинул в папку с MinGW"* Емнип, там две версии в двух отдельных папках: x32 и x64. Не перепутали?

Comment: Tocic - не помогло, HolyBlackCat - Не перепутал.

Comment: Там сложно перепутать

Comment: Также можете посмотреть [подобный вопрос](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823269-Help-setup-CLion-with-SDL2-library) в саппорте CLion

Comment: я по ним уже делал

Comment: Есть видео на английском языке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sIBklOTImI и по нему я делал

Comment: а у вас SDL статический?

Comment: Если я правильно понял то да

Comment: *"Вопрос решён!"* Так какое решение было?